# Computational complexity of DFS is the same as BFS when the result I want is a list of all cycleless paths?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, searching

Given an arbitrary yet low complexity directed graph ($\lt 50 $ nodes), is the computational complexity of a (breadth-first search)-based algorithm the same as that of a (depth-first search)-based algorithm?  Intuitively I think yes.

Am I right?   Not looking for a detailed proof.  I'm just needing to retrieve a list of all paths in a graph of "locations".  The graph is not necessarily a tree.

Btw, I am coding the solution in python, so if you have any opinion on whether BFS > DFS or vise versa here, please weigh in on that too.

Oh yeah, specifically, given two nodes, I want to grab a list of all paths between them, regardless of apparent shortness.  I am aware that there could be infinitely, many, so obviously I mean all cycleless paths, whatever the term is...

Comment: yeah, both have complexity $\mathcal O(E)$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo which one is easier to implement in code?

Comment: In my opinion dfs is usually faster to code so I tend to use it. Also, bfs needs a queue, so I usually implement dfs whenever both work

Comment: If your graph has such a small number of vertices, the running time difference does not matter (unless you are going to re-run the algorithm billions of times), and code clarity should take precedence. Personally I find recursive version of DFS simpler, and there is no difference for non-recursive versions (although, under the hood, if you use vector-based queues, then stack is also simpler than FIFO queue).

Comment: Moreover, please be aware, that you can have an exponential number of paths between a pair of vertices. Clique $K_n$ has [$\lfloor e\cdot (n-2)! \rfloor$](https://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_arrangements) different paths between any pair of vertices.